# Signed Char to Int

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, macos, cocoa, char

Basically, my problem is a signed char to int and string conversion in cocoa.

I found this piece of code in an open source cocoa bluetooth application and am trying to apply it to my own.

Basically, I get a signed char output from the variable "RSSI", and want to convert it to an int and a string, the string for outputting to the log and the int for further calculation. However, no matter what I try, I cannot seem to get it converted, and just get an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS if I try outputting the signed char to the log as it is.

A typical value for the signed char would be " -57 '\307' " quoted directly from the process before it is held up by the NSLog. Here's the code:

```
- (BOOL)isInRange {
    BluetoothHCIRSSIValue RSSI = 127; /* Valid Range: -127 to +20 */

    if (device) {
        if (![device isConnected]) {
            [device openConnection];
        }
        if ([device isConnected]) {
            RSSI = [device rawRSSI];
            [device closeConnection];
            NSLog(RSSI);
        }
    }
    return (RSSI >= -60 && RSSI <= 20);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSLog()` takes an `NSString` format string as its first argument, and an (optional) variable length list of variables for the format specifiers in the format string after that:

`NSLog(@"RSSI: %c", RSSI);`

What you've got now (`NSLog(RSSI);`) is simply wrong. It should be giving you compiler warnings like these:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'NSLog' makes pointer from integer without a cast
warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
```

You should *always* pay attention to compiler warnings, not ignore them. Especially when your program crashes on the same line the warnings refer to, they should be a red flag to you that you've made a mistake.

As an aside, I should mention that `NSLog()` works very much like `printf()`. The two major differences are that `NSLog`'s format string should be an Objective-C string literal (`@"string"`), not a standard C char string (`"string"`), and that the format specifier for an object is `%@`. `%@` is replaced by the string returned by calling the `-description` method on the object to be printed.